# What is the average traffic for a Tor node?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vps

If I buy a VPS to set up a Tor hidden service, then how much traffic will it generate per day according to historical data?
As I know I2P will generate about 10GB per day.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about setting up a *relay*. Not a *hidden service*?

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependent on what kind of service you're offering and how popular it is.
If nobody uses your service then you're not going to generate much traffic.
If you've got a popular hidden service like Silk Road, however, you could generate many gigabytes a day.

Comment: how i can keep it safe?